# Change logo of Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, shapes

I wanted to change the logo. After a huge research I found this -

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function ExtractIcon Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ExtractIconA" (ByVal hInst As Long, ByVal lpszExeFileName As String, ByVal nIconIndex As Long) As Long

Private Const WM_SETICON = &H80

Sub ChangeExcelIcon()
Dim hIcon As Long
hIcon = ExtractIcon(0, "C:\Users\Rokon\Desktop\New folder\ERP_ICON.ico", 0)
SendMessage Application.hWnd, WM_SETICON, False, hIcon
End Sub

Sub ResetExcelIcon()
Dim hIcon As Long
hIcon = ExtractIcon(0, Application.Path & "\excel.exe", 0)
SendMessage Application.hWnd, WM_SETICON, False, hIcon
End Sub
```

All are okay. It changes the logo successfully. But this requires that I have to put the icon in a space of my file manager. But I want that I will insert that logo in my excel sheet then I will link the picture to my VBA code so that I don't need any other file except that excel file.

Hope you understands.

Comment: Upload the image to web and use the URL link.

Comment: I thought also. But I have to consider for the offline user also. Then?

Comment: should the source forcefully be an ico file ? can't you use base64 encoded image ?